# Azure Analysis service - Firewall off deny policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-analysis-services, azure-policy, azure-analytics

I am trying to build a policy to deny disabling firewall in azure analysis service. But not able to deny disabling firewall.

I used below definition but it's not working

```
"if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers/ipV4FirewallSettings",
            "equals": "Disabled"
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "deny"
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other method you can approach to meet your requirement by disabling the firewall for the Analysis service and then apply ReadOnly policy to that service.
[image]

You can also try the below code to create custom policy:

```
{
    "policyRule": {
        "if": {
            "allOf": [{
                    "field": "type",
                    "equals": "Microsoft.AnalysisServices/servers/ipV4FirewallSettings"
                }
            ]
        },
        "then": {
            "effect": "deny"
        }
    }
}
```

Refer to [Hardening Azure Analysis Services with the new firewall capability](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/hardening-azure-analysis-services-with-the-new-firewall-capability/) for more details about Analysis Services and firewall.

Comment: I don't want to deny firwallsetting activities. I just want to deny disabling firewall

Comment: do you want that unauthorized person can't manipulate your firewall by disabling it?